# What film has a girl with short blonde hair pushed onto a conveyor belt crushing machine?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to find a sci fi/horror film that traumatised me when I watched as a child and was way too young to be watching it. I don't remember hardly anything about it except for one scene involved the main bad guy throwing or pushing a girl with short blond hair on to a conveyor belt that led to a crushing machine.

The girl with short hair was wearing rags for clothing and possibly a slave to the main bad guy. I only really remember this one scene which stuck with me. I probably turned it off and ran away after watching it.

I'd say it was made in the 80s and was similar in style to Terminator, Mad Max, and Death Machine. I must have been about 9 - 12 or so when I watched it, which would make it more than 20 years old. It was on a standard TV channel in the UK. I doubt it was a foreign film but it is possible.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! When did you see this? How old was it? What country was it set/made in? What language was it in? Can you describe any of the cast, name any of the actors? Please try to provide some more detail, otherwise I'm afraid this question is likely to be put on hold.

Comment: Related? http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/36429/scifi-movie-from-early-to-mid-90s-with-humans-on-a-conveyor-belt-being-killed

Comment: What makes this relevant to Sci-Fi/Fantasay?

Comment: @Mooz The premise sounds very similar between the questions.

Comment: @DanW I meant that for the OP. There's no explanation of how the question actually relates to SFF.

Comment: Was thinking of "The Perils of Penelope Pitstop"!

Comment: @Mooz Given the accepted answer, it seems this *was* a science fiction film.

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ConveyorBeltODoom

Comment: ahhh Bruce Campbell-ville

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's possible you're looking for "Mindwarp," starring Bruce Campbell.  I was unable to find clips, but the [trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UvGV5RHSaGo/%22Mindwarp%20Trailer%22) does show the crushing machine that so traumatized me as a twelve-year-old.  However, the woman is not blonde.

Comment: I think this is it after reading the following on the Wikipedia article "Seer has Cornelia's slave/foster daughter Claude crushed by an elaborate meat grinder constructed from salvaged parts. It is a quasi-religious ritual attended by the Crawler population, who all drink Claude's blood." I'm pretty sure this is it. I will watch it and report back.

Comment: I found this photo of the girl who gets crushed https://cdn.fstatic.com/media/artists/avatar/2014/12/thumbs/wendy-sandow_a146959_jpg_195x289_upscale_q90.jpg I'm nearly certain this is it.

Comment: It was mindwarp. The scene I remembered is in the following clip. The girl gets her eye ripped out then she is thrown in to the machine. I am so glad to have finally found this. https://youtu.be/VY9uLftjGJY

Comment: Why?? (are you glad)

Comment: I had been searching for this video for a very long time. It gives me some kind of satisfaction to watch this as an adult and no longer be horrified by it.

Comment: @DavidSaunders Glad you got the answer you were looking for. I'm the opposite - movies that I gladly watched when I was younger I now find difficult to sit through. I started to watch The Texas Chainsaw Massacre a few years ago and stopped after a few minutes. Happily sat through it in my teens though.

Comment: @DavidSaunders: As an adult, I'm still pretty horrified by it ^_^

Answer (score 8):

Terminator? There's an intense scene where the terminator pushes Sarah Connor onto a conveyor belt with a crushing thing. She had blonde hair.

Was this it?

Comment: No it's not terminator. Although that is surprisingly close to my description which makes me think the film I seen might have been influenced by terminator. I don't think it was a very successful movie. The girl had short hair as far as I can remember and she is screaming and crying as she realises she cannot escape the crushing device.

Answer (score 7):

Could it be from the tv show Lexx S1E1 - Worship His Shadow? [This scene](https://youtu.be/VVsJrKJ-ZYI?t=1m) looks similar to what you're describing.

Idea of movie from [Movies SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/36429/scifi-movie-from-early-to-mid-90s-with-humans-on-a-conveyor-belt-being-killed) and [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/e1khb/tomt_a_movie_where_prisoners_were_on_an_assembly/).

Answer (score 5):

I bet that its "The Mangler". Its another Steven King fiction about a machine that seems to want to eat people. I remember it but not clearly enough to remember it all the way through. Here is a wikki link:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mangler_(film)

If this is not the correct picture I am for a loss but hope to know the correct one.

Comment: Not The Mangler. The conveyor belt system had bars or something around it so there was no way to get out.

Answer (score -1):

I believe Starchaser: The Legend of Orin also had a scene like that also.

Answer (score -1):

The Hitcher?
The actress had short blonde hair and she was chained between two Semi trucks.they did not show it but she was ripped apart