# Movie where a woman escapes from a dream pod into a red-sand filled world

Tags: story-identification, movie, post-apocalyptic, dystopia

This movie starts out with a young girl who is sleeping in this kind of pod that gives people dreams. This is a post-apocalyptic kind of dystopian world. She hates the dream world and wants to get out. So she escapes and gets out into what is left of her known world which is basically a red sand filled world.

She faces these creepy monster creatures; I don't remember what they look like but they remind me of giant rats or goblins. And they are very violent. Then she meets up with this man, they fall in love and escape these creatures.

At the end they ride off into the sunset but then we pan out to see she is still sleeping in the pod.

Comment: This is a nice description! Just one extra thing, can you remember when you watched the film and if it was new or old at the time? If so you can [edit] that information into the question!

Comment: @Solika: If TheLethalCarrot is correct, you can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Answer (score 9):

#### [*Mindwarp*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0100152/) (1992)

> Combined with Cruel Twist Ending in the early-'90s Fangoria Films release *Mindwarp*. In a post-apocalyptic Earth, the majority of the surface consists of large areas of radioactive wastelands, inhabited largely by violent mutant "Crawlers". The remaining humans, a.k.a. "Dreamers", live in a single biosphere known as Inworld, and spend their time plugged into a computer living out virtual-reality fantasies; while retaining barely enough volition to take care of their basic physical needs. One Dreamer rebels and is exiled from Inworld, fights Crawlers, and searches for her father who was similarly exiled for rebelling. In the end she encounters multiple layers of Dream Within a Dream, as she repeatedly "wakes up" from virtual-reality fantasies; and is ultimately revealed as just another apathetic Dreamer.
>
> <sub>[TvTropes (Warning!), Lotus-Eater Machine](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LotusEaterMachine)</sub>

These are the dream/sleep pods:

[image: The dream pods in the film]

Comment: If accepted, a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/139196/what-film-has-a-girl-with-short-blonde-hair-pushed-onto-a-conveyor-belt-crushing/139214#139214